# How to target site footer on individual page?

Tags: html, css

Html:

```
<footer id="colophon" 
class="site-footer footer 
bg-dark" role="contentinfo">
<div class="container 
footer-inner">
<div class="row">
<div class="footer-widget- 
area"><div class="col-md-3 
col-sm-6 footer-widget" 
role="complementary">
<div id="text-4" 
class="widget widget_text">          
<div class="textwidget"><p>. 
<a href="http://4309.co.uk/
contact/">Contact</a></p>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Tried css:

```
.page-id-3748>.site-
footer{position:relative 
!important;top: 100px! 
important;}
```

Trying to target footer on one page only. I know the selector is `site-footer` but I'm trying to do it with specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the ">" sign inside your CSS.

```
.page-id-3748 .site-footer {
     position:relative !important;
     top: 100px! important;
 }
```

Comment: Nice try but no.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important only if nothing else will work.

Because an id has an higher priority you can use

```
.page-id-3748 #colophon { }
```

or combining 2 class selectors will also give you more priority.

```
.page-id-3748 .site-footer.footer { }
```

or use tags to give it more priority

```
.page-id-3748 footer.site-footer { }
```

If you have used the !important elsewhere on site-footer, then nothing here will work. Also if you have overruled the .site-footer on aother place in your styling this will not wordk.

Comment: Nope. None work. You can check out the page if you like https://4309.co.uk/about-us/ on mobile

Comment: #colophon is in your footer html `<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer footer bg-dark"` For that reason you can use it.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to specify the page height with the page id which would automatically move the footer up?